# Update URLs used by conda for Linux 64 packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am using conda version 3.19.0 from Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. When I try `conda update conda` I receive:

```
$ conda update conda
Fetching package metadata: .......Error: Could not find URL: http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/gpl/linux-64/
```

The output of `conda --debug update conda` is not very informative in this case. But I did notice at http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/ that the correct URL now seems to be:

- http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/**free**/linux-64/

Is there a way to change conda's configuration to look there instead of the **gpl**/linux-64 URL that appears to be deprecated?

I have never manually adjusted .condarc. Will removing the /gpl/... URL there solve it without requiring me to do additional manual URL management and without compromising any other conda defaults or settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspect, this error is caused by an offending entry in your `~/.condarc`, namely the following entry under `channels`:

```
http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/gpl
```

Remove or comment this entry s.t. you're left with the following:

```
channels:
  - http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free
```

Comment: Note: I had an older version of conda, and there was no entry for `http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free` at all (I had never even looked in `.condarc` until hitting this issue). So I actually had to add it, in addition to deleting the entries for now-defunct repos. It would be a nice, but low-priority, feature for conda to have a "refresh-hosts" option or something so that "conda refresh-hosts" could automatically fix this for you, and I wouldn't have to care how Continuum chooses to refactor the repo hosting.